# Relationship between range and enumerations in ontologies

Tags: properties, subclass, owl, ontology, schema.org

So I'm currently working on an ontology which has an EnumerationClass set up in a similar manner to how Enumeration is set up in Schema.org (https://schema.org/Enumeration).

It has subclasses which I'll call ProgramTypeEnumeration and SubstanceTypeEnumeration. Both of these have defined instances. Let's say ProgramTypeEnumeration has instances BasicProgram and AdvancedProgram.

Then there is a property called hasProgramType which relates an AcademicClass class to a program type in the ProgramTypeEnumeration. My assumption is that domain would be AcademicClass and range would be ProgramTypeEnumeration.

That being said, my understanding is that an enumeration is effectively a list. Is it correct to say that BasicProgram is an instance of ProgramTypeEnumeration when BasicProgram is not a list? As well, I'm not saying that hasProgramType has a range of instances of lists of programs, but a range of instances of programs. Would it be better to have a class ProgramType which is a part_of a ProgramTypeEnumeration and then have ProgramType be the range of hasProgramType?

As well, more broadly, is every finite class with a set number of instances technically a subclass of enumeration? e.g. would a class "U.S. State" be a subclass of enumeration if it has exactly 50 instances? Would "ZIP Code" be a subclass of enumeration since it technically also has an exactly number of instances? How do I define whether a class is or isn't an enumeration?

EDIT 1: Attempting to provide a more clear example here.

So Schema.org has an Enumeration subclass which is "MedicalSpecialty" (https://schema.org/MedicalSpecialty). "MedicalSpecialty" has instances which are medical specialties (anesthesia, cardiovascular, etc.).

In Schema.org, the property "medicalSpecialty" (https://schema.org/medicalSpecialty) has rangeIncludes "MedicalSpecialty" (the Enumeration subclass).

Two fundamental questions:
(1) Is there a benefit to having "MedicalSpecialty" as an Enumeration subclass and not a subclass outside of an enumeration?
(2) Is an Enumeration a class which contains lists, and if so, wouldn't an instance of an Enumeration also be a list, instead of a single option? (i.e. wouldn't an instance of the "MedicalSpecialty" enumeration itself be an enumeration?)

Comment: this is an overloaded thread and difficult to parse. you might get better advice if you show your progress and ask a specific question. having said that, an ontology is a list (of terms). "your" ontology orders the list and defines relationships among elements of the list . an "enumeration" is just a label you apply to an ordered list of terms. only you can answer questions about "would it be better" because only you can validate that your graph is an accurate representation of the domain you are describing. if you present a real-world example, others might be able to suggest improvements.

Comment: @JayGray I appreciate the feedback; I've tried to clarify a bit. Unfortunately I was handed something to sort through that I have very little information about and am therefore forced to work on little info. Effectively I do know only that the previous person who worked on this seemed to use much of Schema.org as a backbone. I've never used enumeration and am still having difficulty determining logically why something would be an enumeration or not and how to use enumerations in logical statements. Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main advantage of an Enumeration is that it makes clear to everyone that uses your ontology that a class consists of a finite list of **named** individuals. As for the example you mention of MedicalSpecialty, you will see that Schema.org has a list of "Enumeration Members" that are the named individuals MedicalSpecialty consists of.

An Enumeration and a plain class are indeed very similar. Both an Enumeration and a class consists of individuals (also called instances). The difference is that for a class all the individuals it may consist of is usually not known, but for an Enumeration it is known. Furthermore, a class may have a finite or an infinite number of individuals, whereas an Enumeration has a finite number of known individuals.

If you have a list of named individuals, then it is a good idea to use Enumeration.

Answers to your questions:

(1)  The value of using Enumeration is to make clear to users the expected values to use for properties as for example with the medicalSpeciality property. If a reasoner or rules engine is used, these will be able to pick up errors when example the medicalSpeciality property is used incorrectly.

(2) An Enumeration is not a class that contains lists. Rather an Enumeration is a class that consists of named individuals. Thus, an instance of an Enumeration is an individual just like an instance of a class is an individual. An instance of an Enumeration is not an Enumeration, it is an individual.

If this may be helpful, I have written about Schema.org and OWL on [my blog](https://henrietteharmse.com/2022/01/25/the-difference-between-schema-org-and-owl/).

Comment: I can't thank you enough! This is super helpful!